# Posting to a compojure URL programmatically

Tags: clojure, ring

Is there a way to access routes programmatically (without calling via http).

eg: 
    (defroutes main-routes
      (POST "/query" 
      "OK..."))

can I invoke a "query" function that the defroutes macro generated?

Answer (score 1):

`defroutes` creates a ring handler with the same name that you passed to it. So basically you have a ring handler i.e a simple function that takes a request map and returns a response map.

In your case you can call the function `main-routes` by passing a proper ring request map object that have a `uri` key such that it is being passed to "/query" handler function.

Comment: Thanks ! I almost understand that ! Almost... now need to work out how to make the ring map to satisfy it.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj .. `build-request-map` for reference

Comment: Right, also mandatory ones are covered here: https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/SPEC

So I should be able to call:
(main-routes {:uri ... etc}) as simple as that? (I am trying that, but getting a 404)

Comment: @MichaelNeale the easiest way to build complying requests is to use `ring.mock.request/request`